# Boot virtual Windows 10 KVM from physical machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, linux-kvm

I have a Windows 10 QEMU/KVM setup whose virtual disk is in qcow2 format. I would like to boot my physical machine using this virtual disk. Is it possible to write the content of this virtual disk to a secondary physical disk and boot from it?

I've attempted to search this topic and have only found ways to convert from a physical machine to virtualized but not the other way around. I have a suspicion it should be possible in either direction though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the command. Posting here for posterity:

`qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O raw path_to_your_virtual_disk.qcow2 /dev/disk_you_want_to_write_to`

I had an entire disk to write to and the above command properly wrote Window's recovery, EFI boot, and MSR partition along with all data.

Afterwards, I was able to successfully boot from that disk.